# SVG accessibility causing invalid HTML (duplicate ID's)

Tags: svg, accessibility, screen-readers, wcag

Have an interesting one for the hive. I've done quite a bit of searching about and haven't found an answer to this on S.O. or elsewhere.

I am working on making our website as accessible as possible, this includes providing text alternatives to non-text content. ([WCAG 1.1.1](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/?showtechniques=111))

So far, we've followed the recommendations of CSS Tricks and Sitepoint
https://www.sitepoint.com/tips-accessible-svg/
https://css-tricks.com/accessible-svgs/

by adding: 
`role="img"`
`<title>`
`<desc>`
and `aria-labelledby`, and providing an `id` for each `<title>` and `<desc>`

This works a treat when there is only one of a particular icon on the page. The problem arises when we have the same icon on the page more than once. Because our SVG's are being inlined, id'ing the `<title>` and `<desc>` tags will cause validation errors, which is also a no-no for accessibility. ( [WCAG 4.1.1](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/?showtechniques=111#ensure-compat) )

So the question then becomes, how can we make our SVGs accessible while still maintaining valid HTML? My first thought was to pull the title and desc text into an aria-label on the  tag, but would that then read twice to non-sighted users? Is it fine to leave off the aria-labelledby? Any help is much appreciated!

The full SVG code as it currently stands:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="120px" height="120px" viewBox="0 0 120 120" enable-background="new 0 0 120 120" xml:space="preserve" role="img" aria-labelledby="rings-svg rings-svg-desc" class="rings">
  <title id="rings-svg">Ring</title>
  <desc id="rings-svg-desc">An empty circle ring</desc>
  <g>
    <g>
      <path fill="#E5E5E5" d="M60,112.151C31.245,112.151,7.85,88.756,7.85,60C7.85,31.245,31.245,7.851,60,7.851
      S112.15,31.245,112.15,60C112.15,88.756,88.755,112.151,60,112.151z M60,9.426C32.113,9.426,9.425,32.113,9.425,60
      S32.113,110.576,60,110.576S110.575,87.887,110.575,60S87.887,9.426,60,9.426z"></path>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path fill="#E5E5E5" d="M60,117.5C28.295,117.5,2.5,91.705,2.5,60S28.295,2.5,60,2.5s57.5,25.795,57.5,57.5S91.705,117.5,60,117.5
      z M60,4.075C29.163,4.075,4.075,29.162,4.075,60S29.163,115.925,60,115.925S115.925,90.838,115.925,60S90.837,4.075,60,4.075z"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I'm Having the same problem. would you mind sharing your solution if you have found any?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the `id` inside each element, you may be able to insert the accessible alternatives with the `id` once at the start of the page in a `display:none` element:

```
<div style="display:none">
  <div id="rings-svg">Ring</title>
  <div id="rings-svg-desc">An empty circle ring</desc>
</div>
```

And then insert your SVG in multiple places in your code

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="120px" height="120px" viewBox="0 0 120 120" enable-background="new 0 0 120 120" xml:space="preserve" role="img" aria-labelledby="rings-svg rings-svg-desc" class="rings">
  <title>Ring</title>
  <desc>An empty circle ring</desc>
  <g>
    <g>
      <path fill="#E5E5E5" d="M60,112.151C31.245,112.151,7.85,88.756,7.85,60C7.85,31.245,31.245,7.851,60,7.851
      S112.15,31.245,112.15,60C112.15,88.756,88.755,112.151,60,112.151z M60,9.426C32.113,9.426,9.425,32.113,9.425,60
      S32.113,110.576,60,110.576S110.575,87.887,110.575,60S87.887,9.426,60,9.426z"></path>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path fill="#E5E5E5" d="M60,117.5C28.295,117.5,2.5,91.705,2.5,60S28.295,2.5,60,2.5s57.5,25.795,57.5,57.5S91.705,117.5,60,117.5
      z M60,4.075C29.163,4.075,4.075,29.162,4.075,60S29.163,115.925,60,115.925S115.925,90.838,115.925,60S90.837,4.075,60,4.075z"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'd like to avoid having to add logic to the page if possible. The SVGs are being inlined via React and / or Rails. That would require detecting that more than one of the same SVG was used, right? Otherwise, you could have the same problem where you have created multiple of the same `<div>` still with duplicate `id`s...

Comment: You do not need to count. Insert the `div`, in your HTML, just once. It does not matter if you insert the SVG 0, 1 or 3 times.